# Meta tags missing on dynamic pages for NextJS Application

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a NextJS application and here are the how the pages are laid out:

```
App
--pages
----_app.js
----index.js
----company.js
----users
------[userID].js
```

So, I have a dynamic page [userID].js that get's the userID through router to show information for different users. I am using next/head to generate meta tags dynamically. When I load the pages and I do inspect element I can see the meta tags there. But when I do "view source" for the dynamic page [userID].js, then I don't see the meta tags. I can see the meta tags for all the other pages when I do "view source".

Does anyone know why is that and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems weird. I think `next.js` will wrap everything in `<Head>` on server-side rendering. Could you show how did you add meta tags in `[userID].js`?

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue. No meta tags, even just hardcoded ones, that I add via `<Head>` in a page that uses dynamic routing get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

Next.js router is a client-side router. If you're creating meta tags based on the user information, which depends on the Next.js router, it would be added on a client-side.

So, you would see it in DevTools Elements panel because client-side JS has executed but won't see it in the page source as it just plain server response without JS execution.

It doesn't sound like an issue that needs to be fixed. But you could render the page on the server-side using `getServerSideProps` if these meta tags must be present at first render. However you would lose static optimization for this page.